# Desabilitar botón "Aceptar" de un JFileChooser

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Buenas, necesito ayuda para desabilitar el botón "Aceptar" de un JFileChooser hasta que el archivo no sea seleccionado. De paso quisiera que alguien me dijera qué métodos tiene el filechooser para manejar sus componentes.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Ademas lee: **[¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)** **[edit] tu pregunta** agregando el código que estés usando para lograr lo que describes en tu pregunta y qué errores puedes tener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te cuento que por más que le des al botón abrir, y no selecciones ninguna carpeta o archivo, no va a causar efecto, creo que mejor lo dejas así. Colocalo así:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
int seleccion = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(panel);
```

Te va a abrir el directorio para que selecciones los archivos y listo. Creo que mientras menos te compliques a la hora de programar va a ser mejor para vos y el avance de tu proyecto. En cuanto a los métodos, te recomiendo que utilices un IDE en donde puedas visualizar los métodos de la clase, en mi caso utilizo Spring STS y me resulta maravilloso. Éxitos!